# The firework display, part of the city´s centenary celebrations TAKES place on the 21st August in Cannon Park. - can it be said or written?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

If it is possible to write this sentence (as it was part of a test) :

> The next meeting {WILL TAKE / TAKES} place at 3 p.m. tomorrow. Please don´t be late.

Why can't I write:

> The firework display, part of the city´s centenary celebrations TAKES place on the 21 st August in Cannon Park?

Comment: Not what you asked, but "fireworks" should be plural.

Comment: @EthanBolker Either "fireworks display" or "firework display" are OK, see [New Zealand celebrates 2021 with firework display 'after eliminating Covid-19](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/new-zealand-celebrates-2021-firework-23243678). [Definition of firework display (BrE)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/firework-display) *a public event at which fireworks are set alight/
A huge firework display lit up the night sky.*

Answer (score 1):

> Why can´t I write: The firework display, part of the city´s centenary celebrations TAKES place on the 21 st August in Cannon Park?

Who says you can't?

There are many instances of this pattern easily found in English media.

> The BBC One broadcast follows the live global special which [takes place](https://www.bbc.co.uk/mediacentre/proginfo/2020/16/together-at-home) on Saturday 18 April 2020 and will feature appearances from stars including...
>
> East Kent Open Houses [takes place](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2020/mar/14/an-artists-home-by-the-sea) on 10-11, 17-18 and 24-25 October.

You should probably have a comma after "celebrations", though.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the difference between TAKES place - IS TAKING PLACE - IS GOING TO TAKE place - in that sentence with firework, please?

Comment: We can use the present tense ("takes") if something in the future is scheduled or planned to happen. My train leaves at 3 PM tomorrow. My meeting with the boss is a 9 AM on Monday.