# Ferrari engines factory

Tags: meaning, phrases, nouns, ambiguity

Does the phrase "Ferrari engines factory" have theoretically two meanings?

I think that it can mean either of

1- (Ferrari engines) factory = The factory manufacturing ferrari engines

2- Ferrari (engines factory) = Ferrari's factory manufacturing engines

Do you agree with me? If you don't, can you please tell me why?

Comment: The word before the main noun **factory** is a [*noun adjunct / attributive noun / qualifying noun / noun (pre)modifier / apposite noun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). Such usages are usually ***singular***, but in many cases this isn't a hard-and-fast rule, and there's no doubt that even though ***plural** noun adjuncts* are relatively less common, they do occur more often today than they did many decades / centuries ago. Whatever - in your *specific* context, you should definitely stick with singular.

Comment: Okay let's make it "Ferrari engine factory". I think it has still theoretically two meanings. The first one is the factory manufacturing Ferrari engines, and the other is Ferrari factory manufacturing engines. Do we agree?

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engines+factory%2Cengine+factory&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cengines%20factory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cengine%20factory%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cengines%20factory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cengine%20factory%3B%2Cc0) the relevant NGram usage chart. Even though the plural almost "flatlines" against singular in that chart, there are still a lot of written instances of the collocation ***engines factory***. But I looked at several pages of results without finding a single one where it's an actual noun phrase.

Comment: It's irrelevant to consider the "meaning" of  the phrase "Ferrari engines factory", because ***natve speakers wouldn't use that form of words***. If it was important to distinguish OP's two possible meanings (unlikely, imho), we'd use more wrds to make the intended meaning clear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning / possible ambiguity of a form of words that native speakers don't use anyway.

Comment: Surely, if the engines are made in the Ferrari factory they are by definition Ferrari engines!

Comment: Worth noting that Ferrari don't have a separate 'engine factory'; most of each Ferrari car is produced at their plant at Maranello, with the exception of such things as electrical and electronic items, tyres, seats and windscreen glass, etc.

Comment: As the result, "A Ferrari engine factory" means what? Doesn't it have two possible meanings? (A factory associated with Ferrari engines or a Ferrari factory manufacturing engines)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In a lot of cases where both the singular and the plural can occur, I find the version with a plural noun adjunct more common in AmE. For example I lighted upon [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/245735) yesterday and found myself in agreement with Ethan Bolker in that I'd always say "fireworks". I don't think I've heard "firework" except in a Katy Perry song. I find "firework display" distinctively British.

Answer (score 0):

1. With 2 seconds thought, I have thought of at least *five* meanings of "Ferrari engine factory"
2. You should edit out the typo as it adds further confusion.  (There's no "s".)
3. English is *ubiquitously, overwhemingly, stunningly, amazingly*, ambiguous.
4. Almost every, if not literally every, sentence or fragment in English is ambiguous, usually heavily so.
5. Every single sentence and fragment on this page (just for example) is heavily ambiguous.
6. Mentioning the ambiguity in an English sentence or fragment is like mentioning that the sun rose today.

The answer to your question is "Yes, you're right."

(Note that the word "theoretically" in your opening sentence, is confusing / meaningless.  It "does" have many meanings.  There's no theory or abstraction involved.)

Comment: Your points: 3,4,5 and 6 are just basically, overwhelmingly, earth shatteringly, without any ambiguity, just saying the same thing. It's that simple! Just say it in one sentence instead of repeating it several times. I like the enthusiasm and the exuberant display of language but you do literally tend to repeat yourself. It's like you need to reinforce the concept. You don't have to be so obvious.

Comment: Just kidding  P.S What were the 5 different meanings? To tell the truth I was hoping to see that in the bullet points.

Comment: Thank you first of all. I also think that we may hyphen to solve the ambiguity.
For the first meaning, It can be re-edited as "A Ferrari-engine factory"